# C# - cleaning up event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, garbage-collection

Using C#, i have a method in which I have this code (names are changed)-

```
private void func(...)
{
   ClassName c = new ClassName();

   c.EventName += delegate 
                  {
                    //do some work
                  };
}
```

Now when the method exits, will the event handler be garbage collected, or will it remain in memory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from MSDN,

To prevent your event handler from being invoked when the event is raised, simply unsubscribe from the event. In order to prevent resource leaks, it is important to unsubscribe from events before you dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from an event, the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds that reference, your subscriber object will not be garbage collected.

you can unsubscribe event as follows,

```
  publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent;
```

Comment: But in my code the event handler doesnt have a name. How do i unsubscribe then ?

Comment: you can define a delegate name and do that.

Comment: OK. So using my current design, it is possible that it is not garbage collected ?

Answer (score 4):

It will be garbage collected when the c instance is garbage collected. You do not need to do anything to remove it. The c instance is eligible for garbage collection as soon as the method finishes.

Comment: +1, you don't need to do anything. Unless you don't add some peace of [dark street magic like this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raviramnath/ResurrectionGCRN12222005072151AM/ResurrectionGCRN.aspx) into your `ClassName` finalizer(what you probably don't). I'm just sayin'